# Set grid view width, Android

Tags: android, gridview, view, grid, width

I'm trying to make a calendar activity, which uses Grid view to display the days in the month. It needs to display 7 elements per row which correspond to 7 days of the week. However, when I try to implement it, it doesn't stretch the elements across the entire width of the screens, as there is a small gap at the very right end of the screen as seen in this picture.
 [calendar picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yajEK.png)

This is the xml code I use for grid view:

```
<GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
    </GridView>
```

I'm also using genymotion emulator so I haven't tested it on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check `paddingRight` property of `GridView` parent.